# Does the timestamp type have (hidden) milliseconds?

Tags: mysql-5.7, timestamp

The `updated` column was created as

```
| updated | timestamp | NO | | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
```

a simple `SELECT` gives

```
+---------------------+
| updated             |
+---------------------+
| 2021-12-25 00:15:47 |
+---------------------+
```

Unfortunately, `updated` was not created as `timestamp(3)`.

Is there any way to extract more accuracy from `updated`?
(does MySQL store more precision than the second, even though it shows only seconds?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `<TL;DR>`

To answer the question first:

- Is there any way to extract more accuracy from updated? (does MySQL store more precision than the second, even though it shows only seconds?)

My research strongly suggests that there is **no way** of recovering any more data than was originally stored in the field - which was `TIMESTAMP(0)` - the default value of (`p`) if no precision is specified (see discussion below).

### `</TL;DR>`

The reason that this can be stated with some certainty is that if one looks at the storage requirements for various types [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time), you will see this:

```
Data Type   Storage requirement
Timestamp   4 bytes + fractional seconds storage
```

and just below that, you will see:

[image]

So, what I'm taking from this is that if you choose not to specifically store `TIMESTAMP`s with a higher precision than 0, then you lose all of the higher precision because no space is reserved for that extra precision.

A completely definitive answer would require either a hex editor and fun for all the family exploring the `.ibd` files and/or a trawl through MySQL's source code, both of which are a bit above my pay grade! I think you can consider that your extra precision has gone, or rather, that it never existed in the first place!

### `</TL;DR>`

Having made some errors in comments (since deleted), I decided to actually **test** (as suggested in his comments under his own answer) my assertions (*mea culpa, mea maxima culpa*).

I'm glad to report that I was correct about the rounding issue - if one inserts a time with 6 seconds of precision, the value will be **rounded** and **not** truncated.

All of the code below (unless otherwise indicated) is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5df337bc45c95b2abc91a0c506e0c42e).

### MySQL `TIMESTAMP`s & Timezones!

For MySQL, TIMESTAMPs are stored as seconds since UTC - from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html):

> A timestamp. The range is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' UTC to
> '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999' UTC. TIMESTAMP values are stored as the
> number of seconds since the epoch ('1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC).

As an aside, there is another fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a4f5683e131e71a50d2e7e840428af1a) which shows the difference in MySQL between `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` - the latter datatype doesn't have timezones.

I would **strongly** urge you (or any developer) to **always** use UTC for storing times where possible - it's simpler, cleaner and Daylight Savings Time (DST) is taken care of for you by the server.

Also, if you are obliged to use local timezones, do **not** use an offset (+07:00 in the fiddle) because you then lose any DST information - the reason I did this is because db<>fiddle's MySQL implementation doesn't support time zones (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)), but it does support offsets.

> The MySQL installation procedure creates the time zone tables, but
> does not load them.

### More about MySQL `TIMESTAMP`s:

Anyway, the first thing that threw me was the fact that `TIMESTAMP` without precision is `TIMESTAMP(0)`, but this **is** in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html):

> An optional fsp value in the range from 0 to 6 may be given to specify
> fractional seconds precision. A value of 0 signifies that there is no
> fractional part. If omitted, the default precision is 0.

and from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html):

> (This differs from the standard SQL default of 6, for compatibility
> with previous MySQL versions.)

Fair enough, but they at least `[could | should]` have a [**Server SQL Mode**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) setting to override this, and change it to the SQL Standard behaviour - they've done this before for a **pile** of other MySQL-isms!

Another tricky one (but again [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)) is that `ROUND`ing occurs when you try to squeeze a higher precision fraction into a lower precision field:

> Inserting a TIME, DATE, or TIMESTAMP value with a fractional seconds
> part into a column of the same type but having fewer fractional digits
> results in rounding.

### MySQL's behaviour:

So, now, we'll examine what the behaviour actually is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
  s TIMESTAMP,
  t TIMESTAMP(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  u TIMESTAMP(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  v TIMESTAMP(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  w TIMESTAMP(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  x TIMESTAMP(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  y TIMESTAMP(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  z TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

and then, populate it:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES -- insert the same value 8 times into the different fields!
(
  '2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899',
  '2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899', '2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899', 
  '2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899', '2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899',
  '2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899', '2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899',
  '2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899'
);
```

and then we examine our data:

```
SELECT 's' AS dt, s  AS ts FROM test  UNION
SELECT 't',       t        FROM test  UNION
SELECT 'u',       u        FROM test  UNION
SELECT 'v',       v        FROM test  UNION
SELECT 'w',       w        FROM test  UNION
SELECT 'x',       x        FROM test  UNION
SELECT 'y',       y        FROM test  UNION
SELECT 'z',       z        FROM test;
```

Result:

```
dt  ts
s   2021-12-27 10:30:16.000000
t   2021-12-27 10:30:16.000000
u   2021-12-27 10:30:15.600000
v   2021-12-27 10:30:15.570000
w   2021-12-27 10:30:15.568000
x   2021-12-27 10:30:15.567900
y   2021-12-27 10:30:15.567900
z   2021-12-27 10:30:15.567899
```

So, we can see that (as documented), `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP(0)` (which are the same anyway) are both rounded up from `15.567899` to `16` and that this rounding continues down the line depending on the precision specified - as per the manual!

### So, how to remedy this?

There are two possiblilities - the first is that you are taking old TIMESTAMP(6) measurements from somewhere and you need to **truncate** (and not **round** them - see the [main fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5df337bc45c95b2abc91a0c506e0c42e)), and/or possibly that, going forward, you may want to use `TIMESTAMP(3)` as your field type and `NOW(3)` as your input ([different fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=19294abf021e98266c89d4f18f679f1a)).

- TIMESTAMP(6) measurements:

These will require truncating the values in the `TIMESTAMP(6)` field. This proved trickier than it might appear - see the fiddle for the stages, but the best I could come up with was:

```
TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'), 1, 23))
```

This may appear a bit like going round the houses, but the MySQL [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function has a microsecond granularity but (strangely) not  a millisecond one! Any suggestions for a simpler, more elegant, solution welcome!

This value can then be inserted into a p = 3 `TIMESTAMP` (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5df337bc45c95b2abc91a0c506e0c42e)).

- the NOW() function:

The ([manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)) says:

> If the fsp argument is given to specify a fractional seconds precision
> from 0 to 6, the return value includes a fractional seconds part of
> that many digits.

So, happy days. And checking ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=19294abf021e98266c89d4f18f679f1a)):

```
CREATE TABLE now_test 
(
  s TIMESTAMP,
  t TIMESTAMP(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  u TIMESTAMP(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  v TIMESTAMP(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  w TIMESTAMP(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  x TIMESTAMP(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  y TIMESTAMP(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  z TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Insert eight `NOW(p)` values:

```
INSERT INTO now_test VALUES
(NOW(), NOW(0), NOW(1), NOW(2), NOW(3), NOW(4), NOW(5), NOW(6));
```

And then:

```
SELECT 'NOW()' , 's' AS dt, s  AS ts FROM now_test  UNION
SELECT 'NOW(0)', 't',       t        FROM now_test  UNION
SELECT 'NOW(1)', 'u',       u        FROM now_test  UNION
SELECT 'NOW(2)', 'v',       v        FROM now_test  UNION
SELECT 'NOW(3)', 'w',       w        FROM now_test  UNION
SELECT 'NOW(4)', 'x',       x        FROM now_test  UNION
SELECT 'NOW(5)', 'y',       y        FROM now_test  UNION
SELECT 'NOW(6)', 'z',       z        FROM now_test;
```

Result:

```
NOW()   dt  ts
NOW()   s   2021-12-27 19:28:38.000000
NOW(0)  t   2021-12-27 19:28:38.000000
NOW(1)  u   2021-12-27 19:28:38.600000
NOW(2)  v   2021-12-27 19:28:38.620000
NOW(3)  w   2021-12-27 19:28:38.628000
NOW(4)  x   2021-12-27 19:28:38.628700
NOW(5)  y   2021-12-27 19:28:38.628760
NOW(6)  z   2021-12-27 19:28:38.628767
```

We can see from the example above that if rounding was occurring, the `w` field (`NOW(3)`) would be rounded up to `19:28:38.629` because of the following `7`. A few runs of the fiddle might be necessary in order for this to become obvious!

### Size on disk:

I tried to find a query to obtain the individual sizes of MySQL's fields on disk, but MySQL apparently doesn't expose this information - at least not through its SQL interface. PostgreSQL has the [`pg_column_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html) function and there's also the [`pageinspect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/pageinspect.html) contrib extension for those who like mucking about with hex dumps and [bit-twiddling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation).

The best I could come up with, short of getting a hex editor and/or digging into MySQL's source code was this (see bottom of fiddle):

```
SELECT
  table_name  AS "The table",
  data_length AS "Data length"
FROM
  information_schema.tables
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'test'
ORDER BY
  1 + 2
DESC;
```

Result:

```
The table   Data length
     test         16384
```

So, 16kB for 8 records. A quick search reveals ([manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-space.html)):

> Each tablespace consists of database pages. Every tablespace in a
> MySQL instance has the same page size. By default, all tablespaces
> have a page size of 16KB;

On the same page, there is mention of [innodb_page_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_page_size';
```

Result:

```
Variable_name   Value
innodb_page_size    16384
```

So, all the `Data Length...` query above is telling us is that we've used 1 page of disk space for a tiny table - hardly surprising and not much help there. See my discussion in the `<TL;DR>` introduction about storage requirements to see why (in all probability) your extra precision bits have gone to that great bit bucket in the sky... *de profundis...*.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to extract more accuracy from updated?

No. It is not possible to select the data which is absent in the table and cannot be calculated from the data present in the tables.

> does MySQL store more precision than the second, even though it shows only seconds?

No. It stores exactly what you asked for. It can store up to microsecond - but you have not asked for this accuracy.

> Well, it really is déjà vu all over again with this question! There appears to be a bug in MySQL's implementation of this... (quelle suprise - a bug in MySQL...) at least on dbfiddle.uk and dbfiddle.com. – Vérace - get VACCINATED NOW

You call `NOW()` - and you get the datetime without milliseconds. Call `NOW(3)` or `NOW(6)` and get more accurate value.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ccaf9b2c25e372c7bf0ca82c66ded787

> Well, good news from the MySQL camp - you don't need to worry about fractional values of a second at all - 5.7 doesn't support them – Vérace - get VACCINATED NOW

Never consult the person from the MySQL camp who said this nonsense again.